# NSAttributedString with UILabel (ios 6): Using line height attribute and attributes from IB

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, nsattributedstring

I have a multi-line UILabel whose dynamic text is what I wish to format. The only formatting I need to do is increasing the line height so that the difference in the heights of two lines in one label is bigger.

Question 1: How do I go about doing it via NSAttributedString? I tried hands on that but the format is very "non-UIKit" and hence confusing and the documentation is very limited.

Question 2: I could see that attributed text can be added via Interface Builder but that of course is for the static text. Is there any way where I can just set the attributes in IB and then supply the text via code, since I would like the formatting to be done to all of the text and not parts of it?

Answer (score 0):

In interface builder you can set custom attributes/properties. You could add a category on UILabel that adds a property CSSStyle. Then in the setCSSStyle you would take the NSString that is currently on text, change that into an NSAttributedString and set that via setAttributedText.

To convert the CSS style you put into this property you would use a framework like my DTCoreText or if that is big for you, then you could simply use a quick&dirty CSS parser (I have one built on NSScanner in DTCoreText) and do the conversion of the attributes you need to NSAttributedString properties.

Coming to think of it, you probably would want to set an HTML string on such a property because then you could format different words differently. DTCoreText has a method to convert HTML to NSAttributedString and then you would again set this via the standard setter.